# 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Data.DataSetExtensions.dll VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, exception

I use this code to get data from the database. In other conditions like If ProductCombo.Text = "All"  this code works perfectly. But in this condition it gives `'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Data.DataSetExtensions.dll` exception. I cannot understand what it is. Please help.

```
If ProductCombo.Text = "All" Then
            If CheckDate.Checked = True Then
                Dim salesTbl As DataTable = SilexDatabaseDataSet.Tables("Sales")
                Dim query = _
                            From sale In salesTbl.AsEnumerable() _
                            Where sale.Field(Of DateTime)("Date") >= DateTimePicker1.Value _
                            Select sale
                Try
                    Dim boundTable As DataTable = query.CopyToDataTable()
                    FilterGrid.DataSource = boundTable
                Catch ex As Exception
                    MessageBox.Show("No data found")
                    FilterGrid.Visible = False
                    SalesDataGridView.Visible = True
                End Try
            Else
                Dim dv As DataView
                dv = New DataView(SilexDatabaseDataSet.Tables("Sales"), "", "Date Desc", DataViewRowState.CurrentRows)
                FilterGrid.DataSource = dv
            End If
```

Comment: " In other conditions like If ProductCombo.Text = "All" ... ". Your code _is_ all about ProductCombo.Text= "All". Sure you pasted the correct code? Btw...which line is throwing the exception?

Comment: Exception is in `Dim boundTable As DataTable = query.CopyToDataTable()` line. Btw, Thanks for you reply @AlexB.